# Подскажите пожалуйста, как заполнять поле в админке джанго

Tags: django, django-admin

Как можно заполнять значение поля в дефолтной админке джанго, через бэк, чтобы она как бы автокомплитом было заполнено, при этом админ даже не знает о существовании этого поля

```
# model.py
from django.db import models


class Menu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    parent_nesting =

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

# admin.py 
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Menu


# Register your models here.
@admin.register(Menu)
class MenuAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'parent']
    fields = ['name', 'parent']
```

Мне нужно заполнить поле parent_nesting, по правилу, если parent определен то значение будет parent.parent_nesting + 1, а если нет, то 1, или

```
parent_nesting = 1 if parent is None else parent.parent_nesting + 1
```

Если бы это прислал пользователь то можно было бы через serializer его заполнять, но с админом хз что делать

Answer (score 0):

Решение было таким в файле admin.py нужно было переопределить функцию save_model
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)